# How to print a character that is not found in the keyboard

Tags: c++, char, dev-c++

I'm trying to print the following characters in the screen using std::cout :

- '│'
- '┼'
- '─'

Unfortunately, it returns an unexpected value like "Γöé" in the screen. I've already solved this problem in the past using cout and I used the same process (First copy the character from the character map then open the code in notepad++ then I paste the character in there then compile the code in DevC++). The character changes when I open it in DevC++ after saving it in notepad++ but the weird thing is that its not like before(when I paste the char '█' in notepad++ then open it in DevC++, the character will be 'â–ˆ' unlike before which is 'Û'.
Any other ideas please?

OS: Win10
IDE: Dev C++

Comment: Look for a text encoding option in your project options.

Comment: This is because your c++ source file encoding and the windows console (or file) encoding do not match. You could now switch source code encoding to the required one or use escape sequences to get the desired characters (I personally prefer principally keeping sources in utf-8, but would have to live with escape sequences then). Alternative: switch console encoding appropriately before starting your program - I'd assume WinAPI even offers means to do it programmatically, but not sure about. If possible, the latter would be my preferred solution.

Comment: There are 3 encodings involved. The encoding used in source code (or text file if you read it from such), the encoding used at runtime inside the text variable, and encoding used by your terminal. You need to be aware of them all.